# Show that $T = \sideset{}{_1}{T} + c\sideset{}{_2}{T}$ is invertible if $T = \sideset{}{_1}{T} + i\sideset{}{_2}{T}$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T\in \sideset{}{_n}{GL}(\mathbb{C}) $ is an invertible complex matrix, then we can write $T = \sideset{}{_1}{T} + i\sideset{}{_2}{T}$ with $\sideset{}{_1}{T}, \sideset{}{_2}{T} \in Mat(nxn,\mathbb{R})$, show that there exists a real number $c \in \mathbb{R} $, so that the matrix $\sideset{}{_1}{T} + c\sideset{}{_2}{T}$ is invertible.

I'm trying to show it through the determinant. Since the determinant of T can't be zero, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Side note: Writing $T_1$ is a lot easier than you seem to think. It's enough to type `T_1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Determinants and sums of matrices do not play along very nicely, so there is no direct route to finding an expression for the determinant of $T_1 + cT_2$. However, here is something to get you started: $f(x) = \det(T_1+xT_2)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients. Is there some way you can tell that this is not the zero polynomial?